# Angular table index is undefined with multiTemplateDataRows directive

Tags: angular, indexing, row, mat-table

I'm having trouble getting my table indexes to show up. Here's an example table:

```html
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows>

    <!--Column definitions-->        
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{columnProp.name}}" *ngFor="let columnProp of columnProps; let i = index;">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
            {{columnProp.name}} {{i}}
        </mat-header-cell>

        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let j = index;">
            <div>{{element[columnProp.name}} {{j}}</div>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!--Row definitions-->
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>

    <!-- Row content-->
    <mat-row
        *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let k = index;"
        matRipple
        (click)="this.expandRow(row, k)">
    </mat-row>

    <!--Expanded row content-->
    <mat-row
        *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedContent'];"
        [@detailExpand]="row == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
    </mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Column index `i` and `j` show up as expected, but when I click on my row, the index `k` shows up as undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`multiTemplateDataRows` have a different variable to hold the row's index called `dataIndex`. Access the row's index using `let k = dataIndex`.

```html
<!-- Row content-->
<mat-row
    *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let k = dataIndex;"
    matRipple
    (click)="this.expandRow(row, k)">
</mat-row>
```

[Relevant github issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/12793)

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight difference between regular `mat-table` elements and `mat-table` elements with the `multiTemplateDataRows` directive.

With the regular `mat-table`, there is only the option of using the row index by accessing the `index` attribute.

With the `multiTemplateDataRows` directive, there is an option to access the index of the data itself using `dataIndex`, and also the order it is rendered in using `renderIndex`:

```
<!--normal Table-->
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let i = index;"> {{i + 1}} </mat-cell>

<!--multiTemplateDataRows Table-->
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let i = dataIndex;"> {{i + 1}} </mat-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let j = renderIndex;"> {{i + 1}} </mat-cell>
```

Answer (score 0):

Context provided to the row cells when multiTemplateDataRows is true. This context is the same as CdkCellOutletRowContext except that the single index value is replaced by dataIndex and renderIndex.

Ref to documentation: https://material.angular.io/cdk/table/api#CdkCellOutletMultiRowContext